# Is there any way to send arguments/values to Robot test cases from jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, robotframework, testcasesource

I have automated test which takes input from the user and runs the test.
Any idea on if we can give the argument from jenkins for the robot testcase and run the test?

ex: 
scenario: Test if a lighting device works well or not.
steps:

1. ssh login to light device,
2. run some predefined set of commands,
3. verify the lighting_flag set to 0 or 1,
4. ssh logout from device

In this case, 
I need to take light device username and password as input from user.
Is it possible to get it from jenkins (build with parameters) and run the robot test case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use variables. For example, a user keyword connecting and logging in might be like:

```
Connect To Device   
    [Arguments]    ${HOST}
    Open Connection     ${HOST}
    Login    ${USERNAME}    ${PASSWORD}
```

Now, provided your Jenkins parameters are `username` and `password`, you can use the execute shell task like this:

```
 pybot --variable USERNAME:[username] --variable PASSWORD:[password] <path/to/tests>
```

This sets global variables ${USERNAME} and ${PASSWORD} for the test execution.

More info in the [user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#setting-variables-in-command-line).

Comment: This worked for me using the robot command and same args. Is pybot synonymous with the robot command?

Comment: @dave_g_ Yes, one could call them synonyms. In fact, pybot is the predecessor of robot command (at least planned to be so)

Answer (score 1):

Passing Arguments from Jenkins.

1. Go to Jenkins Job_Name -> Configure, in Job Notification area you can find a checkbox named "This build is parameterised".
2. Click on "Add Parameter" select "string parameter" in options.
3. Now you can find Name, Default Value, Description(optional).

Name: USERNAME

Default Value: user1

Repeat the same for password.
In Execute Shell:

export USERNAME=$USERNAME

export PASSWORD=$PASSWORD